Does photocurrent depend on intensity or on number of photons?
Edit: I have realised my mistake. The part of text I read assumed the light to be monochromatic and so in that case, there will be no difference between intensity and number of photons because the frequency remains same. Thanks to @planetmaker
Anyway here's the original question:
Any textbook I have read so far says that the amount of saturation current depends on intensity but not frequency.
How can the two (viz. intensity and frequency) be unrelated when intensity is quite literally defined as energy falling per unit area in a unit time and energy $E$ is simply proportional to frequency $\nu$ as
$$E=h{\nu}$$
So the intensity of a light source producing $n$ photons per unit time and each photon having energy $E$ is given as
$$I=\frac{nh\nu}{A\cdot t}$$ ($A$ and $t$ represent area and time respectively)
So in a scenario where I keep the number of photons $n$ constant but change the frequency $\nu$, will the saturation photocurrent change?
If it does not change, does that mean the statement, “Saturation photocurrent depends only on intensity and not frequency” is invalid and it should rather be, “Saturation photocurrent depends only on number of photons incident per unit time and not frequency”?
PS: I have read answers to similar questions but I didn’t get a clear clarity from any of those.

What is the difference (for monochromatic light) between 'intensity' and 'number of photons?

Where did you read that "Saturation photocurrent depends only on intensity and not frequency"?

@planetmaker I get it now. I was wrong

You have it right.
You can idealize it as each photon kicks off one electron. (It might be really that each photon kicks off one avalanche.) So current is proportional to number of photons.
If the photons are bluer, they kick the electron harder. But they don't kick any more electrons.
Think about the Photoelectric effect

In that case why do you think the textbooks and internet have generalised the idea that photocurrent solely depends on intensity rather than conveying it as number of photons?

This assumes the spectrum doesn't change when you turn up the intensity.

The current depends on the number of photons with high enough frequency(energy). 1 radio photon and 1 gamma photon will give you 1 electron, because gamma photon has enough energy to expell an electron and radio photon doesn't have enough energy. So, intensity of light is proportional to current but you only count photons with sufficient energy.
